# Urban Airship SDK Integration in iOS & push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, urbanairship.com, devicetoken

We have integrated Urban SDK using these [guidelines](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#urban-airship-sdk-setup).

We have tried to check the push notification using ad hoc profile where we have set below values in **AirshipConfig.plist**

- `inProduction=YES`
- `productionAppKey=OUR PRODUCTION KEY`
- `productionAppSecret= OUR PRODUCTION SECRET`

Please check the below code which we have implemented in the AppDelegate file of project.

---

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching: (UIApplication *)application
{
.
.
.
.
 UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
 config.automaticSetupEnabled=NO;
 [UAirship takeOff:config];

 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        NSLog(@"------------REGISTER DEVICE------------: >= 8");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"------------REGISTER DEVICE------------: <8 ");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
.
.
.
.

}

#pragma mark Remote Notification methods


-(void) application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken // Device Registration
{
    [[UAirship push] appRegisteredForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:devToken];

}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    [[UAirship push] appRegisteredUserNotificationSettings];

}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"NOTIFICATION------------ didReceiveRemoteNotification ------------ %@", userInfo);
    [[UAirship push] appReceivedRemoteNotification:userInfo applicationState:application.applicationState];
}
```

---

When we are trying to send the notification to the registered device token, the server shows that device token as **INACTIVE** Device token.

Please **show me** what should I do for this.

Comment: Are you actually IN PRODUCTION or are you testing on your device from Xcode? If not, set it to false.

Comment: @QuentinHayot , i have created the build using adhoc profile and testing it in real device.

Comment: But it's still testing, it's not a release build, so you have to use the Development mode.

Comment: Actully in AirshipConfig.plist there are 5 key values.

inProduction,developmentAppKey,developmentAppSecret,productionAppKey,productionAppSecret

So if i am using adhoc profile , i should use 
inProduction = true ,productionAppKey= key,productionAppSecret=secret. Isnt it ?

Comment: are you making this app for the app store ?

Comment: @QuentinHayot : I have tried with Development mode also. its still shows inactive

Answer (score 0):

So, first it looks like you are missing a few app [delegate methods](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#automatic-integration).

Urban Airship handles APNS registration. Remove your manual registration calls as UA will just override them, and instead, enable notifications with `[UAirship push].userPushNotificationsEnabled = YES;`. It should prompt the user to accept notifications, and then the Urban Airship channel should be opted in.